# fresh cordova build from angular2 build white screen on android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, angular, cordova

I copied my angular2 folder to a new folder, ran npm I etc. in Angular it runs fine.

I created a Cordova folder in my folder with

```
cordova create cordova be.volckaertachiel.be "volckaertAchiel"
```

then:

```
cd cordova
cordova platform add browser
cordova run browser
rm -r www
cd ..
```

build it in the corodova folder with:

```
 ng build --target=production --environment=prod --output-path cordova/www/
```

And then ran it in the browser with `Cordova run browser`

After I changed my backend(node.js API) to accept port `8000` it ran like it was running in angular2

After this `Cordova platform add android` and then `Cordova build android`

it launched the Android SDK, it launched the app, but it has a white screen...

**My issue in short**: I build my web with Cordova -> runs fine, on android I just get a white screen.

**Updated Issue**: compiled js files aren't found in android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with not finding the files is fixed by setting from this `<base href="/">` to this `<base href="./">` it's also explained here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1769

Comment: You did my day after investigation that took 5 hours. Thanks, actual for Cordova..

Answer (score 3):

This is solution may be application if you want are running on android 8.0 emulator/device with angular 8.

For android 8.0 emulators, it does not support ES2015 which is ES6.

- Go to your angular project
- Then edit the target to "es5" in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else get here with this problem without lucky: in my case, i had to change the script in index.html, removing the scripts wicht type was "module" and removing the attribute "nomodule".

In other words, i changed from this:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="main-es5.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="runtime-es5.js"></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js"></script>
<script src="main-es5.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

It looks like it has something to do with what mingliang94 said, but my emulator is android 9.

Comment: White screen is gone as you mentioned in my case, I am using Angular 8.x, but Angular routing is showing only the root page and when I redirect to other page I see again the root page inside of the other pages.

Comment: I'm using Routes, RouterModule and Router (navigateByUrl). The app is running in an Android 5.1 (tablet). Angular 8.

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities for this type of behavior:

**1. Splash screen misconfiguration**

Check your `config.xml` and verify that you have:

- Configured your splash screen to hide automatically
- Specified valid splash screen images.

Here's a sample config for Android that will hide the splash screen after 10 seconds:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/ldpi.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/mdpi.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/hdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xhdpi.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/xxhdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
</platform>
```

**2. Index page bug**

Check your `index.html` stored in `www`. Is it missing? Is it empty? Does it load a white page when you open it in a browser?

If the `index.html` file is present and loading properly in a web browser then you will need to inspect the app while it's running on your Android device. It's likely throwing a JavaScript error during page load that's preventing anything from being displayed. To do so, follow these steps:

- Enable developer mode debugging on your Android.
- Connect your device to your computer via USB.
- Compile the app for debug and run it on your Android device: `cordova run android --debug --target=YOURDEVICEIDHERE`
- Open up Chrome on your desktop and navigate to `chrome://inspect`

You can live inspect your app just like you would a regular web page. Hitting the refresh button will re-run the initial load and allow you to log any errors.

Comment: Which config file do you mean? also, i do have a bug on android... 
these are mostly the same as on just the html file...

i do all my requires like this: 
'./routing/app-routing.module';
https://imgur.com/a/EwjpU

Comment: @AchielVolckaert Every Cordova project should have a single `config.xml` file located in the root directory of the project. 

It looks like you have a lot of errors in your code -- seems your compiled app can't find the files you've included in your `index.html`. Do you have those same errors when loading your code in a browser? How does your `index.html` include those files? Your include lines probably need to be fixed.

Comment: it includes it like this: "src="inline.d3540de41b22ba427b55.bundle.js"". those files do exist( https://imgur.com/a/jLn0Q ). the files that are included before those build files( like font-awessome.min.css in the assets folder) are no issue

Comment: @AchielVolckaert Have you checked to see if they are present in the compiled Android build assets folder, located here: `\ROOTFOLDER\platforms\android\assets\www`? If the files are not in that folder, then you may need to re-build the project for Android (or simply remove and re-add the android platform).